# compare id with javascipt

Tags: javascript, click, counter

I have this function that count the number of click to change the css and check the checkbox in a div. This function is link to multiple different div. I would like to reset the count to 0 when I click on a different div.

```
<script> 
var clicks = 0;

function onClick(a, b, c) {
  clicks++;

  if (clicks == 1) {
    a.checked = true;
    b.checked = false;
    c.className = "class1";

  } else if (clicks == 2) {
      a.checked = false;
      b.checked = true;
      c.className = "class2";
  } else if (clicks == 3) {
      clicks = 0;
  } 
}
</script>

<div id="A1" class="class3" onclick="onClick(cb1,cb2,this)">
     <img src="image.jpg"/>
     <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="1" />
     <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="2" />
</div>
<div id="A2" class="class3" onclick="onClick(cb3,cb4,this)">
     <img src="image.jpg"/>
     <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" value="3" />
     <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" value="4" />
</div>
```

Comment: Use a constructor or a class, so you can have a `new` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this: (Store last id you clicked, if it changed, reset the counter)

```
<script> 
var clicks = 0;
var prev = '';
function onClick(a, b, c) {

  if(c.id != prev) {
    clicks = 0;
    prev = c.id;
  }

  clicks++;

  if (clicks == 1) {
    a.checked = true;
    b.checked = false;
    c.className = "class1";

  } else if (clicks == 2) {
      a.checked = false;
      b.checked = true;
      c.className = "class2";
  } else if (clicks == 3) {
      clicks = 0;
  } 
}
</script>

<div id="A1" class="class3" onclick="onClick(cb1,cb2,this)">
     <img src="image.jpg"/>
     <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="1" />
     <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="2" />
</div>
<div id="A2" class="class3" onclick="onClick(cb3,cb4,this)">
     <img src="image.jpg"/>
     <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" value="3" />
     <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" value="4" />
</div>
```

Comment: @AlexandreCharest if it's good, can you please accept this as an answer?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just did it ;)